# Find and remove a character in subdirectory names recursively with find, sed and mv

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh

I am trying to remove a character in subdirectories recursively but can't seem to nail the correct answer. I am running BSD and would like to achieve this with find, sed and mv. I am a beginner in scripting and in the use of sed so any help would be appreciated.

I have directories named in different subdirectories

```
dir/foobar 01
    foobar 02
    foobar 03
dir2/foobar 01
     foobar 02
     foobar 03
```

I want to remove the 0 in every directory name

```
dir/foobar 1
    foobar 2
    foobar 3
dir2/foobar 1
     foobar 2
     foobar 3
```

I have gotten this far with find and sed but don't know how incorporate the mv command

```
find . -type d -name "foobar 01" | sed 's/0//g'
```

This prints the right reformat but without the mv command it doesn't do anything further...

Is there a way to do this with one command for all matching subdirs or do I have to go each case seperately?

Thank you.

Comment: Another tool to look at is [`zmv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv): `autoload zmv; zmv '(dir*)/(foobar )0(*)' '$1/$2$3'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `zsh` you can use recursive globs.

Given:

```
% tree .
.
├── dir
│   ├── foobar 01
│   ├── foobar 02
│   ├── foobar 03
│   └── foobar 4
└── dir2
    ├── foobar 01
    ├── foobar 02
    ├── foobar 03
    └── foobar 2

11 directories, 0 files
```

You can use this recursive glob to find the directories with `0` in the name and rename them. This also tests if the renaming would erase an existing file or directory:

```
#!/bin/zsh
# ^ that path deponds on your system.

for fn in **/*0[0-9]*/; do
    nfn="${fn//0}"
    if [[ -e $nfn ]]; then  
        echo "$nfn already exists! NOT renaming $fn=>$nfn"
        continue 
    fi     
    echo "renaming: $fn=>$nfn"
    mv "$fn" "$nfn"
done
```

Result:

```
% tree .
.
├── dir
│   ├── foobar 1
│   ├── foobar 2
│   ├── foobar 3
│   └── foobar 4
└── dir2
    ├── foobar 02
    ├── foobar 1
    ├── foobar 2
    └── foobar 3

11 directories, 0 files
```

The same script works with Bash if you add `shopt -s globstar` above the loop.

Comment: What do I do with that script? How do i run it?

Comment: I will add the sheebang to the top. The *easiest* is to save that in a txt file and then `zsh that_txt_file` in the directory that is the root of the target directories. [HERE](https://linuxhint.com/run-zsh-script/) is a how to.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. Do you know a source where I could learn about the syntax of this script? Because all of the **, {}, [] and $'s are making my head spin...

Comment: I managed to try this one as it was quite elegant and I understood it quite well after some research. Only thing that was wrong was that some directory names have zeroes in them and the sctript removed them too. I didn't find a solution for this yet, can you help?

Comment: I meant there were zeros in the parent directory names.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you do not want to rename?

Comment: For example year in the parent directory name, like this Parent Directory (2023) - foobar 01, foobar 02 etc.

Comment: Your script toook the 0 out of 2023 also when I ran it from the same directory as the parent.

Comment: You can change the glob pattern to `**/*\ 0[0-9]*/` to only find files that have a space in front of the `0`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use a combination of find, sed, and xargs to rename the directories recursively.

Something like this should get the job done:

```bash
find . -type d -name "foobar 01" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed "s/0//g")"'
```

Here's an explanation of the command:

`find . -type d -name "foobar 01" -print0`: This is used to find all directories (`-type d`) named "foobar 01" and prints them using a null character (`-print0`). The null character is used to handle directories with spaces in their names.

`xargs -0 -I {} sh -c '...'`: This takes the output of `find` (null-delimited list of directories) and applies the specified command to each one. The `{}` is a placeholder for the input.

`mv "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed "s/0//g")"`: This is the command that is executed for each directory found. It uses mv to rename the directory. The `sed` command is used to remove the '0' character from the directory name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you break the command down so I can learn more about the syntax?

Comment: @TerryBishop is it safe to assume it worked for you?

Comment: Not yet. I am able to test it on the weekend. A few questions: what does sh -c do? How can I test this command before real execution?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your question right and you have the directories named 'foobar' and subdirectories 01, 02, 03

Here is how you can list them recursevly:

```
for DIR in $(find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*0*"); do echo "$DIR"; done
```

Here is how you can check the desired result after they are processed:

```
for DIR in $(find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*0*"); do echo "$DIR" | sed -E 's/0//g'; done
```

And finally here is the command for processing them:

```
for DIR in $(find . -type d -name "*0*"); do mv "$DIR" "$(echo "$DIR" | sed -E 's/0//g')"; done
enter code here
```

Comment: No, the directories have a space in the name "/dir/foobar 01" "/dir/foobar 02" etc. Can you run those commands from the CLI directly?

Comment: Yes, you can try them, but I'm fairly sure it might not work because of the space...